# Workaround to cast a Chrome Application Shortcut to Chromecast?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

When you make a website into an application shortcut you don't get the toolbar in the top, where the chromecast button (from the Chromecast extension) is located. Therefore, you cannot cast a Application Shortcut tab. This is true even if you add the --enable-extension flag to the application shortcut flag.

Is there any workarounds that will let me chromecast such a tab?

I'm thinking something like an extension that enables you to set the chromecast command to a keyboard shortcut, or one that adds the chromecast command to the right click menu, but I haven't found anything like that yet. If not, could I make such an extension myself or is it not possible to call other extensions like that?

Comment: I have the same problem, it sucks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is right-click on the title bar and click "Show as tab." After that, everything came up. Bookmarks, extensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/)
Scroll to the bottom and press keyboard shortcuts.